# FireBug – limit FB to certain domain only?

Tags: firefox, firebug

Is it possible to limit FireBug to work only on certain domains? e.g. all domains that contain `*dev*` in it. I didn't manage to find any sort of "settings" for FireBug in FireFox settings.

I know I can exclude domains. But that's not the same.

---

After looking around, I've discovered a topic where FB developers say that

> There is no need for such option because FB is disabled by default.

But that's not true! Example, when I go to to http://cssmania.com my whole browser freezes and then after 15 seconds or so I get a message saying that FireBug couldn't execute some script, do you want to Stop the script?

Answer (score 0):

Firebug *is* suspended by default. Re-suspending Firebug, however, in not intuitive. First, you must add the Firebug icon to a toolbar with:

```
View > Toolbars > Customize...
```

Now, to suspend Firebug:

- **Right-click** the icon and **uncheck** `On for All Web Pages`
- **Right-click** the icon and **click** `Clear Activation List`

This should fix the problem you are having with Firebug running when you do not want it to.